# Is an integral of a density function of a random vector a density or probability?

Tags: probability

By [Srivatsan Narayanan](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/63794/1281):

> I think the expression $$\int_{\mathbb R} f_{X_1, X_2}(x,x) dx$$ is
>   the density of the distribution of the RV $X_1 - X_2$ at 0. It is not
>   the probability that $X_1 - X_2=0$.

By [Robert Israel](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63794/probability-of-iid-random-variables-to-be-equal/63797#63797):

> It (the probability that $X_1 - X_2=0$) should be $P(X_1 = X_2) = \iint_D f_{X_1}(x) f_{X_2}(y)\ dx \ dy$,
>   where $D = \{(x,y) \in {\mathbb R}^2: x = y\}$.

My question is:

For some integral of a density function of a random vector, how can one tell if the integral is the **density** of some r.v. at some value, or the **probability** of some other r.v. at some value?

Is it a density if and only if the dimension of the integral is strictly less than the dimension of the original random vector, and a probability if and only if the dimension of the integral is equal to the dimension of the original random vector?

I feel a little hard/unnatural about this. Maybe I am missing some knowledge?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Can you clarify what dimension (of an integral or a random vector) means?

Comment: For dimension of an integral, two possiblities: the dimension of the subset the integral is taken, or the number of iterated integrals that the original integral can be converted to when possible. I think the two are the same thing? For dimension of a random vector, it is the dimension when viewing the r.v. as a vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure others will provide a mathematically correct answer. I will instead focus on some intuitive ideas and heuristics.

**Dimensional analysis.** Imagine that the quantity $x$ is not a number but a physical quantity like length. In that case, the dimension of both $x$ and $dx$ are $[L]$ (which is the same as saying they have the unit $\text{m}$, for meters). Remember that the density has the dimension that is the inverse of this, i.e., $[L^{-1}]$. Why? Because 
$$
\Pr[a \leq X \leq b] = \int_a^b f_X(x) dx,
$$
and the probability is always a number. Analogously, if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are two random variables with dimension $[L]$ each, then the joint density $f_{X_1, X_2}(x_1, x_2)$ has the dimension $[L^{-2}]$. This is because:
$$
\Pr[(X_1, X_2) \in \mathcal D] = \int_D f_{X_1, X_2}(x_1,x_2) dA,
$$
where $dA = dx_1 dx_2$ is an area element.

Now, coming to your integral, it has the dimension of $[L^{-2}] \cdot [L] = [L^{-1}]$. This reminds us of a one-dimensional density, and not a probability. Thus the density option does look more plausible.

**Degenerate vs. non-degenerate events.** *I do not think I am using the proper terminology here; I will appreciate if someone helps improve the answer.*

This is essentially an elaboration of Robert's answer (but [in my own words](http://pichaus.com/wattoom-zink-pubbawup-gazork-@911d3fd1ffb157c0e23066faca4cf751/)). By *degenerate*, I essentially mean that the event is a subset of zero measure. Let's take the event $X_1 = X_2$. This is a line $l$ (through the origin, slope $1$) in the plane; so it has zero measure. *If* the joint distribution has a continuous density, then we will expect that the integral over any region $\mathcal D$ of zero will be zero. As an example of this, take the case when $X_1$ and $X_2$ are iid and have density $f_X(x)$.

Before I proceed further, note that in general the joint variable need not have such a density, however well-behaved $X_1$ and $X_2$ are. For example, take $X_1 \sim U(0,1)$, and *define* $X_2 := X_1$. In this case, the joint random variable takes values only on the line $l$. The above logic breaks down because the density now takes the form $\delta(x_1 - x_2)$, and is not continuous.

Going back to your example, we have convinced ourselves that the probability *should* be zero, but the integral you wrote down would not be in general. This suggests that the integral cannot represent the probability.

Comment: @Tim Please let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: Thanks! I understand your reply basically. As for dimensional analysis, to avoid guessing, what does the notation $[L]$ mean, some unit for measuring something? Is it used often in Physics?

Comment: @Tim You're welcome. By "my reply", do you mean this answer? (As for dimensional analysis, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis#Definition. It's essentially the same as units, but they use different symbols for reasons not clear to me. And yes, it's used more often in physics.)

Comment: Yes, I mean I can understand this answer.