# Probability of 2 discrete i.i.d. random variable to be 0.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are 2 random i.i.d. variables. What is the probability of $P(X_1 = X_2)$. 
\begin{equation} P(X_1=X_2) = \sum_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} P_{X_1,X_2}(i,i) = \sum_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} P_{X_1}(i)^2.
\end{equation}

Similar question with same proof- [Probability of iid random variables to be equal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63794/probability-of-iid-random-variables-to-be-equal) But there doesn't seem to be a convincing answer for the discrete case for at least me in the thread. Or I couldn't understand it properly.

Comment: There must exist some number $i$ such that $P_{X_1}(i) > 0$, therefore the sum can never be zero.

Comment: Exactly as stated above. If $X_1 = X_2 \equiv 0$ is the constant zero random variable then it is probability 1

Answer (score 0):

We have

$  p\left( {{X_1} = {X_2}} \right) =   \\
  \sum\limits_{x \in {\Omega _{{X_1}}} \cap {\Omega _{{X_2}}}} {p\left( {{X_1} = {X_2} = x} \right)}  = \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad {\text{by total probability}} \\
  \sum\limits_{x \in {\Omega _{{X_1}}} \cap {\Omega _{{X_2}}}} {p\left( {{X_1} = x,{X_2} = x} \right)}  = \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad {\text{by transitivity of equality}} \\
  \sum\limits_{x \in {\Omega _{{X_1}}} \cap {\Omega _{{X_2}}}} {p\left( {\left. {{X_1} = x} \right|{X_2} = x} \right)} p\left( {{X_2} = x} \right) = \quad {\text{by the product rule}} \\
  \sum\limits_{x \in {\Omega _{{X_1}}} \cap {\Omega _{{X_2}}}} {p\left( {{X_1} = x} \right)} p\left( {{X_2} = x} \right) = \quad \quad \quad \quad {\text{if }}{X_1}{\text{ and }}{X_2}{\text{ are independent}}  \\
  {\sum\limits_{x \in {\Omega _{{X_1}}} \cap {\Omega _{{X_2}}}} {p\left( {{X_1} = x} \right)} ^2}\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \;\;{\text{if }}{X_1}{\text{ and }}{X_2}{\text{ have same probability distribution}}  
$

Comment: How to proceed forward now?

Comment: @AQ To proceed forward to what please?